# Adding css class in Struts 1.3 Forms and other Html input fields

Tags: jsp, struts-1

How to add css class in Struts 1.3 forms and Html input fields?

I can't use struts 2 framework.I have to use only older version in my project.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `styleClass` attribute.

It might be a good idea to read the docs; also this question is scattered throughout SO.